# Is 10,000 images for one class of spectrograms good enough for music classification model?

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification

I'm debating on using a DNN or CNN for this classification, but I have 10,000 spectrograms of songs. I was wondering if I need more because the images have a low variants.

Comment: Are you classifying by genre? If so, you should have plenty of data; at least hundreds of examples per class. Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Emre Yes, I'll carry on then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with Emre. One thing that can be helpful when asking the question is to look at comparable datasets since there's usually some around. For spectrograms for example, there are [150,000 samples w/ 12 labels here](https://www.kaggle.com/ollmer/labels-spectrograms-exploration/data), [2890 samples here](http://deepsound.io/dcgan_spectrograms.html), and [1 million samples with various labels here](http://mirg.city.ac.uk/codeapps/the-magnatagatune-dataset).

Find a few examples and gauge a rough order of magnitude of samples per class given how close the tasks are to yours. That should give you at-least a starting point. Then, if lets say one set is very large, usually someone will have [written a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.01789) using that set, and that can help start both the architecture and size jumping off point (and maybe a baseline for transfer learning) of your task.